# This merchant is not enabled for google pay

Tags: android, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, google-pay

I have implement Stripe SDK which supports pay using Google pay. All working good but it's give me a one error like :

> This merchant is not enabled for google pay

Already generate **merchantId** in Play store console and try to run app from production but still not working.

I found some code like `merchantInfo` add in my code but i can't find any example where to i use this below code:

```
merchantInfo: {
    merchantName: "Example Merchant",
    merchantId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Please inform me if anyone knows about this bug

[image]

Comment: https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/support/troubleshooting

Comment: i already check this but i can't understand how this link work. @DarShan

Comment: Make sure to work in the TEST environment until you are assigned a production-enabled merchantId by the Google Pay team. See https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#paymentsclient

Comment: *you are assigned a production-enabled merchantId by the Google Pay team.* Already assigned. @JoseLUgia

Comment: I see! Make sure to double your merchantId: in your message above, you say you obtained it from the Play store. The merchantId you need should be taken from Google Pay instead: see https://payments.developers.google.com/signup. If that's all okay, the next step would be to look at the entire request where you are sending the `merchantInfo`. Also, are you already in touch with the support team?

Comment: *If that's all okay, the next step would be to look at the entire request where you are sending the merchantInfo.* I follow this link [Google Pay with stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/mobile/android/google-pay) there is no code for **`merchantInfo`** so how to i send `merchantInfo`?. **AND** *are you already in touch with the support team?* Yes i already get support but at that time there is no response from support team. @JoseLUgia

Comment: Oh, I see, you are integrating on Android (my mind was on the Web). To have production access, you need two things to happen: 1. [Request production acccess](https://services.google.com/fb/forms/googlepayAPIenable/), 2. Your application needs to be pointing to production, signed with your release keys, and be enabled under [your Google Pay developers profile](http://payments.developers.google.com/signup) ([more on that](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/test-and-deploy/deploy-your-application)).

Comment: Hey, Have you solve that?

Comment: This is now easily managed using [Google Pay's Business Console](https://pay.google.com/business/console). From there, you can see all your integrations with their status, and keep track of their progress getting approved for `PRODUCTION` access.